# Maybe monad construction

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I'm currently struggling with a new element of Haskell: Monads. Therefore I was introduced to this by an example of creating a `(>>=)` operator that executes a function on a `Maybe` type (taking its actual integer value as argument to it) only if it's not equal to `Nothing`, and otherwise return `Nothing`:

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
(Just x) >>= f = f x
```

However, I'm not quite sure how this works with the following usage of it:

```
eval (Val n) = Just n
eval (Div x y) = eval x >>= (\n ->
    eval y >>= (\m ->
        safediv n m))
```

It seems to me that the `(>>=)` operator simply takes one `Maybe` value and a function that returns one, however in this example usage code it seems like it's taking 2 times a `Maybe` value and once a function. I was told however that it evaluates `x`, puts the result in `n`, then evaluates `y`, puts the result in `y`, and then executes the `safediv` function on both. Although I don't see how the `(>>=)` operator plays its role here; How does this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read it like this:

```
eval (Div x y) = eval x >>= (\n ->
    eval y >>= (\m ->
        safediv n m))
```

when you want do `eval (Div x y)`then

- first `eval x`:
- - if was `Just n` (using the first **>>=**)
- - then take the `n` and have a look at `eval y` (using the first **>>=**)
- - - if the last is `Just m` (second **>>=**)
- - - then take the `m` and do a (second **>>=**)
- - - `savediv n m` to return it's result - you still have the `n` from your closure!.

in ever other caes return `Nothing`

So here the `(>>=)` just helps you to deconstruct.

Maybe it's easier to read and understand in the `do` form:

```
eval (Val n) = Just n
eval (Div x y) = do
    n <- eval x
    m <- eval y
    safediv n m
```

which is just syntactic sugar around `(>>=)`

#### let's chase the cases:

1. `eval x = Nothing` and `eval y = Nothing`:

```
eval x >>= (...) = Nothing >>= (...) = Nothing
```

2. `eval x = Nothing` and `eval y = Just n`:

which is just the same:

```
eval x >>= (...) = Nothing >>= (...) = Nothing
```

3. `eval x = Just n` and `eval y = Nothing`:

```
eval x >>= (\n -> eval y >>= (...))
= Just n >>= (\n -> eval y >>= (...)) 
= Just n >>= (\n -> Nothing)
= Nothing
```

4. `eval x = Just n` and `eval y = Just m`:

```
eval x >>= (\n -> Just m >>= (...))
= Just n >>= (\n -> Just m >>= (...)) 
= Just n >>= (\n -> Just m >>= (\m -> safediv n m))
= (first >>= for Just) = Just m >>= (\n -> safediv n m)
= (second >>= for Just) = safediv n m
```

Comment: That's what I thought too however I don't see how this works with the (>>=) function that's used twice, first (the way I read it) on a value with another value, and then again on the result of that and a function. However the operator only takes a value and a function?

Comment: @user2999349 it's just *used* to get first the "n" from "Just n" and then the second time to get the "m" from "Just m"

Comment: @user2999349 It's two separate applications of `>>=`  The inner one has the arguments `eval y` and `(\m -> safediv n m)`, while the outer one has as arguments `eval x` and `(\n -> eval y >>= (\m -> safediv n m))`

Answer (score 1):

Let's do element chasing to illustrate how it works.  If we have

```
eval (Div (Val 5) (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)))
```

Then we can break this down into

```
eval (Div (Val 5) (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)))
    = eval (Val 5) >>=
        (\n ->
            eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)) >>=
                (\m ->
                    safediv n m
                )
        )

-- eval (Val 5) = Just 5

    = Just 5 >>=
        (\n ->
            eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)) >>=
                (\m ->
                    safediv n m
                )
        )

-- Just x >>= f = f x

    = (\n ->
        eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)) >>=
            (\m ->
                safediv n m
            )
      ) 5

-- Substitute n = 5, since the 5 is the argument to the `\n ->` lamba

    = eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)) >>=
        (\m ->
            safediv 5 m
        )
```

Now we need to take a detour to compute `eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1))`...

```
eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1))
    = eval (Val 0) >>=
        (\n ->
            eval (Val 1) >>=
                (\m ->
                    safediv n m
                )
        )

-- eval (Val 0) = Just 0
-- eval (Val 1) = Just 1

eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1))
    = Just 0 >>=
        (\n ->
            Just 1 >>=
                (\m ->
                    safediv n m
                )
        )

-- Just x >>= f = f x

eval (Div (Val 0) (Val 1))
    = (\n ->
        (\m ->
            safediv n m
        ) 1
      ) 0

    = (\n -> safediv n 1) 0
    = safediv 0 1
    = Just 0
```

And now back to our original call to `eval`, substituting `Just 0` in:

```
eval (Div (Val 5) (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)))
    = Just 0 >>= (\m -> safediv 5 m)

-- Just x >>= f = f x

eval (Div (Val 5) (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)))
    = safediv 5 0

-- safediv x 0 = Nothing

eval (Div (Val 5) (Div (Val 0) (Val 1)))
    = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
eval (Val n) = Just n
```

from this we conclude that `eval` produces a `Maybe` value. The second equation, let's rewrite it as

```
eval (Div x y) = 
  eval x >>= (\n ->
                    eval y >>= (\m ->
                                      safediv n m ) )
```

i.e.

```
eval (Div x y) = 
  eval x >>= g 
             where
             g n =  eval y >>= h 
                               where
                               h m =  safediv n m
```

See? There is only *one* function involved in each `>>=` application. At the top, it's `g`. But `g` defines – and uses – `h`, so `h`'s body has access both to its argument  `m` and the `g`'s argument, `n`.

If `eval x` produced `Nothing`, then `eval x >>= g` is just `Nothing`, immediately, according to the `>>=` definition for the `Maybe` types (`Nothing >>= _  =  Nothing`), and no `eval y` will be attempted.

But if it was `(Just ...)` then its value is just fed to the bound function (`Just x >>= f  =  f x`).

So if both `eval`s produce `Just ...` values, `safediv n m` is called inside the scope where both arguments `n` and `m` are accessible. It's *probably* defined as

```
safediv :: Num a => a -> a -> Maybe a
safediv n m | m == 0    =  Nothing
            | otherwise =  Just (div n m)    -- or something
```

and so `h :: m -> Maybe m` and `g :: n -> Maybe n` and the types fit,

```
-- assuming a missing type of "expressions", `Exp a`,
eval :: Num a => Exp a ->                                       Maybe a    
  -- Num a is assumed throughout, below
  eval (Div x y) =                                           -- Maybe a
  -- Maybe a >>= a ->                                           Maybe a
      eval x >>= g 
                 where
  --               a ->                                         Maybe a
  --                   Maybe a >>= a ->                         Maybe a 
                 g n =  eval y >>= h
                                   where
  --                                 a ->                       Maybe a
                                   h m =  safediv    n    m  -- Maybe a
  --                                      safediv :: a -> a ->  Maybe a
```

as per  the type of bind for the Maybe monad,

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> 
              (a -> Maybe b) -> 
         Maybe            b
```