# What is the Maybe type and how does it work?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am just starting to program in Haskell, and I came across the following definition:

```
calculate :: Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
```

Comment: What is the thing you are not able to understand ? What error are you facing ? I would suggest you to try initially before posting question.

Comment: Is it actually a valid definition? (a note: I referred to a revision that began with `function calculate` on the same line)

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Libraries/Maybe

Comment: @Sibi I would suggest you to try to read the question before posting your answer.

Comment: @zerkms thanks for the note,  I meant to type function_calculate.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? There is no duplicate and I guess it's sometimes hard to understand the wiki since it starts talking about *monads* almost immediately.

Comment: I agree man after I had read the wiki, it didn't make much sense, but your answer with the examples helped a lot, cheers CommuSoft.

Comment: Looks to me like you're getting a bit ahead of yourself. I suggest you take a step back from what you're dealing with and [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: You might benefit from the answer I wrote to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808258/what-does-the-just-syntax-mean-in-haskell/18809252#18809252

Comment: @Levi, thanks for the recommendation that is a great explanation!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Maybe a` is an ordinary data type defined as:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

There are thus two possibilities: or you define a value of type `a` as `Just a` (like `Just 3`), or `Nothing` in case the query has no answer.

It is meant to be defined as a way to define output for non-total functions.

For instance: say you want to define `sqrt`. The square root is only defined for positive integers, you can thus define `sqrt` as:

```
sqrt x | x >= 0 = Just $ ...
       | otherwise = Nothing
```

with `...` a way to calculate the square root for `x`.

Some people compare `Nothing` with the "null pointer" you find in most programming languages. By default, you don't implement a null pointer for data types you define (and if you do, all these "nulls" look different), by adding `Nothing` you have a generic null pointer.

It can thus be useful to use `Maybe` to denote that it is possible no output can be calculated. You could of course also error on values less than `0`:

```
sqrt x | x >= 0 = Just $ ...
       | otherwise = error "The value must be larger or equal to 0"
```

But errors usually are not mentioned in the type signature, nor does a compiler have any problem if you don't take them into account. Haskell is also shifting to *total* functions: it's better to always try at least to return a value (e.g. `Nothing`) for all possible inputs.

If you later want to use the result of a `Maybe a`, you for instance need to write:

```
succMaybe :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
succMaybe (Just x) = Just (x+1)
succMaybe _ = Nothing
```

But by writing `Just` for the first case, you somehow warn yourself that it is possible that `Nothing` can occur. You can also get rid of the `Maybe` by introducing a "default" value:

```
justOrDefault :: a -> Maybe a -> a
justOrDefault _ (Just x) = x
justOrDefault d _ = d
```

The builtin `maybe` function (note the lowercase), combines the two previous functions:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe _ f (Just x) = f x
maybe z _ Nothing  = z
```

So you specify a `b` (default value) together with a function (`a -> b`). In case `Maybe a` is `Just x`, the function is applied to it and returned, in case the input value is `Nothing`, the default value will be used.

Working with `Maybe a`'s can be hard, because you always need to take the `Nothing` case into account, to simplify this you can use the [*Maybe monad*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240534/haskell-maybe-monad-construction).

---

*Tom Schrijvers* also shows that `Maybe` is the successor function in type algebra: you add one extra value to your type (`Either` is addition and `(,)` is the type-algebraic equivalent of multiplication).